# What is the "source" attribute of the Context element of an Apache Tomcat configuration file for?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, tomcat

It's somehow related to Eclipse.  For example:

```
<Host>
    <Context docBase="foo" path="/foo" reloadable="true"
        source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:foo" />
</Host>
```

Comment: It's certainly not a standard attribute (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html). Where did you see it?

Comment: It's in the server.xml that was generated when I created a Tomcat server in Eclipse (in the Servers tab) and I added the "foo" project to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Eclipse WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) adds the `source` attribute to the project-related `<Context>` element to identify the location of the source code associated with the context (thus, the actual project in the workspace which has been deployed to this server from inside Eclipse).

If you wondered about this due to a warning during Tomcat's startup, since Tomcat 6.0.16 any "unrecognized" XML tags and attributes in the `context.xml` or `server.xml` will produce a warning about it during the startup, although there's actually no means of a DTD.

Just ignore it. Tomcat shall work fine and Eclipse is happy with it. It won't occur in real production environment with a worthfully WAR file.